# Would there be a conflict in CVS project in eclipse when using DAO layer

Tags: eclipse, cvs, dao, conflict

I just wonder if there would be a conflict in CVS project in this kind of setup.
I'm currently creating a web application in eclipse. So I have a DaO layer which all CRUD operations in the database will be perform.

So lets say, I have an Employee Table which has an EmployeeDao class. What if I am using that class and adding some method I needed and also one of my team is also modifying the EmployeeDao class to add method to suit his needs. So would there be a conflict if that happens? What should be the proper approach in this kind of set up.?

I would greatly appreciate any idea guys.

Thanks!

Comment: each of you when commit , will optionally add a comment , and then when you look at the version history of that prog you can see who commited when , and can compare your local prog with the version that you select , to find the difference

Comment: Conflicts like this can arise in any part of any kind of project. There is nothing special about DAO's. So, the answer is generic.

Comment: Upgrading from CVS might be a great idea.

Comment: ah I see,, thanks for your suggestions... as of now we have not come in to that situation of having that conflict. I just want to know what are the possible solutions just in case that problem arise. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're both editing the same file then yes - there will be a conflict.

However, that's not to say that you need to worry about it.
If the changes are not in the same location in the file then the merge facility in your source control should be fine.

If you've both overwritten the same function then you would get a conflict.

Best approach is communication with your development team; If you do Sprint then in your daily meeting you can declare which files you might be working on for example; also if you're going to make a massive change to a class - email your development team.

Also, If you're dealing with multi-users in your development phase then I *strongly* suggest that you consider a newer Source control system; SVN is much better then CVS and Git or Mercurial are even better again.

Comment: Thanks for immediate answer. I haven't use any of those control system, but I will look at those for possible enhancement of our development.